# Apache Byte Range and Audio File

Tags: apache, security, audio, audio-streaming

Apache on our servers are configured to block byte ranges ([CVE 2011-3192](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CVE-2011-3192)). But its making the audio we have on our server not to play as newer versions of Safari and Chrome requests them in Bytes, but server sends the entire content.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than completely blocking the Range header, you could try setting apache to only block the range header if too many requests are made. From the [Apache Wiki:](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CVE-2011-3192)

Use SetEnvIf or mod_rewrite to detect a large number of ranges and then
   either ignore the Range: header or reject the request.

Option 1: (Apache 2.2, requires mod_setenvif and mod_headers)

```
      # Drop the Range header when more than 5 ranges.
      # CVE-2011-3192
      SetEnvIf Range (?:,.*?){5,5} bad-range=1
      RequestHeader unset Range env=bad-range

      # We always drop Request-Range; as this is a legacy
      # dating back to MSIE3 and Netscape 2 and 3.
      #
      RequestHeader unset Request-Range

      # optional logging.
      CustomLog logs/range-CVE-2011-3192.log common env=bad-range
```

The number 5 is arbitrary. Several 10's should not be an issue and may be
required for sites which for example serve PDFs to very high end eReaders
or use things such complex http based video streaming.